# Resize placeholder text to fit input text field bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input field in a form as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h2><label class="control-label">Email Id*</label></h2>
    <input type="text" name="entry.724320362" value="" class="form-control" id="entry_724320362" dir="auto"
           required="true" placeholder="Email id with which you have registered for The portal"/>
</div>
```

This form, when displayed in browser, shows full placeholder text. But when on mobile, it clips it as this:
[image]

So is there any way using bootstrap(or otherwise) I can make the placeholder either resize to fit the text field or perhaps wrap text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use besudo classes to style the placehllder:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {}

:-moz-placeholder {}

::-moz-placeholder {}

:-ms-input-placeholder {}
```